# What sort of founder crops and/or domesticable food plants can be found in the tundra/subarctic, specifically the Alaska interior?

Tags: alternate-history, civilization

Another attempt at a broad question I asked here earlier. My aim here is to build another cradle of civilization from the ground up, in an area that never did (for fairly obvious reasons) and in an area that could serve as a sort of connection point between the Old World and New World.

For most the part I am getting together a rough idea of what I need to do and where I want to go with things but I am have trouble getting the initial setup going, this is where the plausibility factor might be kicking this entire idea in the groin.

To get to the point are there any plants in the interior of Alaska, specifically the Yukon River basin, that could serve as a founder crop to serve as the catalyst for further plant domestication and ultimately sedentary civilization. I haven't been able to find much, not sure if its due to a lack of resources on the topic, a lack of knowledge on my part as to where to look or a lack of said plants in the region.

I mean the area could certainly provide a decent supply of food for locals, especially with proper agricultural practices, winter preparation, advanced/complex food preservation techniques, etc. For instance Alaska does produce oversized record breaking vegetables due to loads more sunlight during the summer.

Thanks again

Comment: *"Could certainly provide a decent supply of food for locals":* You mean, a decent supply of food for *very few* locals. *"Loads more sunlight":* More sunlight than Severnaya Zemlya, maybe. But just about any place in the contiguous 50 states of the USA or in China gets more sunlight than Alaska, and that's without mentioning places such as Mesopotamia or Egypt. (The point being that places at high latitudes are cold exactly because they don't get much sunlight.) The sad but simple truth is that Alaska cannot support a large human population, and certainly not without modern technology.

Comment: Wikipedia says "The average temperature now for the Yukon River Basin is approximately 30 °C (86 °F) in the summer and −40 °C (−40 °F) in the winter." It sounds like you could grow most anything during the Summer and next to nothing in Winter.

Comment: Try looking up wild rice, it's a tall grass that grows out of ponds with large grains. While i've never seen it growing up here, I imagine it  defiinitely could be imported from lake athabasca or a similar climate in canada

Comment: @AlexP  FUN FACT: Every lat and long on earth receives the same amount of sunlight over the year

Comment: @R.Rankin: Have you paid attention in geometry class? At higher latitudes the sun is lower in the sky. Were it not for the inclination of Earth's axis of rotation, the amount of sunlight received by the unit area at latitude $\lambda$ would be proportional to $\cos \lambda$; the inclination of the axis of rotation mitigates this, so that at the poles the amount of sunlight is not zero, but it is still very much smaller than on the Equator.

Comment: @R.Rankin: I think I understand where the confusion comes from. Yes, if we disregard clouds etc. the total number of hours of sunlight over a year is the same everywhere; but one hour of sunlight gives different amounts of sunlight at different latitudes. The amount of sunlight falling on a square meter during an hour mid-day in Timbuktu is much larger than the amount of sunlight falling on a square meter during an hour mid-day in Murmansk.

Comment: @AlexP that's why we grow on south facing slopes (terraced hillsides), completely makes up for that, you just want your slope to roughly be the same angle as your latitude. In fact, per *flat* acre of land your actually catching more rays than you can in lower latitudes

Comment: @R.Rankin: That is not an scalable escape, quite obviously, because of the shadow of the slope extends exactly in proportion so that the sloped surface takes up the same horizontal area as would be needed to capture the amount of sunlight. In the end, for agriculture only the flat horizontal surface area counts. Growing stuff of the sun-facing slopes is indeed a good solution which allows the farmer to grow something instead of nothing, but it does not provide them with free land.

Comment: @AlexP of course lol, I'm just speaking from personal experience btw, I live here. You have to carefully plan a farm, but if carefully thought out it can provide a similar biomass of food compared to a lower latitude (yes not scalable). Where the extreme latitudes truly have a food producing advantage  though is in ocean biomass,  mostly brought about by higher oxygen/gas solubility. most of the world eats fish/crab et cetera brought from such areas. There are some major aquaculture projects currently underway here.

Comment: OP. check out the Chocolate lilly also known as "northern rice root" pretty interesting plant, actually just look at this book: https://www.fao.org/3/ai215e/ai215e.pdf

Comment: @AlexP Just one more thing *"In the end, for agriculture only the flat horizontal surface area counts"*  Come on now, the Incan civilization might beg to differ, it's all terraced. throughout the Andes. The OPs question is about possible plants/methods of agriculture to allow a civilization.

Comment: And if you look carefully, the terraces add up to the area of the horizontal projection of the sloped surface, don't they?

Comment: @R.Rankin That book will be extremely helpful, I appreciate you digging that up. I had originally gone looking in that direction but hadn't found much literature or info on the topic online.

Comment: @AlexP in theory yes, in practice no. You tend to get taller plants  against the warm side walls of the terrace, ultimately looks like a continuous slope of green if done properly. Then by the good ol Pythagoras theorem, you are getting more surface area normal to the sun's rays than a mere horizontal projection not saying it's easy, just that it's doable

Answer (score 9):

**Aspen.**

https://www.fs.usda.gov/wildflowers/beauty/aspen/grow.shtml

[image: aspen range]

Aspens grow in the Alaskan interior.  They will dominate an area until shaded out by pines.

> Quaking aspen is an aggressive pioneer species. It readily colonizes
> burned areas and can persist even when subjected to frequent fires. In
> the Central Rocky Mountains, the extensive stands of aspen are usually
> attributed to repeated wildfires. It may dominate a site until
> replaced by less fire-enduring but more shade-tolerant conifers.

The seeds and bark of aspen are edible.

https://www.ediblewildfood.com/quaking-aspen.aspx

> Edible Parts Much of the tree is edible. You can eat the inner bark
> and cambium but it is best in the spring. It can be dried, ground into
> a powder and used as a flour. For those who have used it, they say
> that this flour is normally mixed with other flours for making bread.
> It also can be used as a thickener for soups. This tree can be tapped
> for the sap and it can be made into syrup. Catkins can be consumed raw
> or cooked...

Your people have been working on the aspen.  They keep the pines from shading them out.  They select for trees with big fat catkins and lots of them.  It helps that aspens can grow as clones.

> Aspen is noted for its ability to regenerate vegetatively by shoots
> and suckers arising along its long lateral roots. Root sprouting
> results in many genetically identical trees, in aggregate called a
> "clone". All the trees in a clone have identical characteristics and
> share a root structure...

If you want Fat Caskin Tree to take over the area, give it room.  I could imagine your sedentary aspen keepers have different named tree clones, each good for something particular - Fatty as noted above.  Sweetbark the flour trees are kept as saplings to maximize tender bark production.  Sapmasters are of course is made into that staple of civilization, beer.

Comment: my only question would be could aspen be selected for greater and thicker bark production?

Comment: @andreswendish - I dont know why not.  You can select for any trait.  I had this idea that maybe you could eat the entirety of the young shoots (little tree clones), which a big tree produces in plenty.  I live outside aspen territory so someone else will have to do the experiment.

Comment: See that what I figured as well. Just couldn't find anything conclusive on if it had been done with another bark tree "crop" like cinnamon. Then again the different between original maize and what we have today would point to the ability for selective breeding to be extremely powerful